# Inverting a big.matrix object in R

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I have a 39,547 x 39,547 variance matrix, V, stored as a big.matrix object, as the memory required for storing this size of matrix is just beyond the capabilities of my machine.

```
w <- as.big.matrix(test[,1:3]) # 39,547x3 matrix
V <- w %*% big.t(w)
```

I then need to calculate `z^T %*% V^(-1) %*% z`, where z is vector of length 39,547, hence I need to either perform

1) chol(V), followed by backsolve and crossprod, or
2) solve(V) (ideally not)

However, these functions don't work on big.matrix objects, and in the bigalgebra package there only appears to be ways of multiplying these objects together.

I have also attempted to perform this calculation via big.PCA:

```
big.PCA(V)
[1] 39547 39547

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.7 Gb
```

Does anyone have experience with performing these sorts of calculations with large big.matrix objects?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to numerically invert a big matrix. It is not only numerically extremely expensive, but also inaccurate as floating point errors accumulate. Sets of linear equations involving large matrices are best solved iteratively, without inverting the matrix.

Comment: Check this out... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/solving-very-large-matrices-in-pieces